# How to extract text between two | in R dataframe with a regex

Tags: r, regex, string

I want to extract the text from a column in a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
genes=TraesCS5A01G391700;is_HC;ANN=A|missense_variant|MODERATE|TraesCS5A01G391700|TraesCS5A01G391700|transcript|TraesCS5A01G391700.1|protein_coding|7/8|c.539C>T|p.Ala180Val|539/735|539/735|180/244||,A|missense_variant|MODERATE|TraesCS5A01G391700|TraesCS5A01G391700|transcript|TraesCS5A01G391700.2|protein_coding|7/7|c.562C>T|p.Arg188Trp|562/621|562/621|188/206||
```

What I want to get is the first occurrence of the text between `|`
In this example is: `missense_variant`. I want the results in a list. I was trying something like these:

```
res_ann <- rm_between(vcf_ann$INFO, "|", "|", extract=TRUE)
str_extract(vcf_ann$INFO, regex(""))
```

The first case returns me all the results between `|`, and the second, well couldn't match with any regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
str_extract(vcf_ann$INFO, "(?<=\\|)[^|]+(?=\\|)")
```

or even (if you do not need to check for the trailing `|`):

```
str_extract(vcf_ann$INFO, "(?<=\\|)[^|]+")
```

**Details**

- `str_extract` obtains the first match from the given string
- `(?<=\\|)` - a positive lookbehind that requires the presence of `|` immediately to the left of the current location
- `[^|]+` - 1 or more chars other than `|`
- `(?=\\|)` - a positive lookbahead that requires the presence of `|` immediately to the right of the current location.